# Moving Postgresql - download all data and table creation, but without indexes

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to move postgresql between two servers. There's `rsync` connectivity between the two servers.

My tables are large, around 200GB in total with nearly 800 million rows across 15 tables. For this volume of data, I found that `COPY` command for the key tables was far faster than the usual `pg_dump`. However, this only dumps the data.

Is there a way to dump only data this way, but also then dump the database creation script -- which will create the tables, and separately indexes? I'm thinking of the following sequence:

1. `COPY` all tables into file system. Just 15 files, therefore.
2. `RSYNC` these files to the new server.
3. On the new server, Create a fresh PG database: tables, foreign keys etc. But no indexes yet.
4. In this fresh PG database, `COPY FROM` all the tables, one by one. Slightly painful but worth it.
5. Then create the indexes, all in one go.

I'm seeing ways to get some scripts for #3 and #5 dumped by PG on the older server. The complication in the PG world is the `OIDs` for tables etc. Will this affect the tables and data on the new server? The [`pg_dump` reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) is a bit cryptic in its help material.

For #3, jsut the creation of the "schema" and tables, I could do this:

```
pg_dump --schema-only  mybigdb
```

Will this carry all the OIDs and other complications, thereby being a good way to complete step #3?

And for only #5, not sure what I'd do. Just the indexes etc. Will I have to look inside the "schema only" file and separate out the indexes?

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the `OID` they are only used internally. I am a bit surprised about your claim that `copy` is faster then `pg_dump` + `pg_restore`. A plain text dump will actually use `COPY` and a custom dump can be restored with multiple threads. But both will essentially do what you are planning to do: create the tables, load the data, create the indexes.  Another option to clone a complete Postgres instance is `pg_basebackup`

Answer (score 3):

Funny, the sequence you are describing is a pretty good description of what `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` does (with some oversights: e.g., for performance reasons, you wouldn't define a foreign key before you restore the data).

So I think that you should use `pg_dump` instead of reinventing the wheel.

You can get better performance out of `pg_dump` as follows:

- Use the directory format (`-Fd`) and parallelize the `COPY` commands with `-j number-of-jobs`.
- Restore the dump with `pg_restore` and use `-j number-of-jobs` for several parallel workers for data restore and index creation.

The only drawback is that you have to wait for `pg_dump` to finish before you can start `pg_restore` if you use the directory format. If that is a killer, you could use the custom format (`-Fc`) and pipe the result into `pg_restore`. That won't allow you to use `-j` with `pg_dump`, but you can still parallelize index creation and such with `pg_restore -j`.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. Just to be sure, what would be the precise commands be for a restore where the system is devoted to PG, and has 32GB RAM, and has nothing else happening at the moment?

Comment: That depends on the name of the dump directory, the PostgreSQL superuser name and the host, port and database names of the new server. The value for `-j` would depend on the number of cores, and how much your I/O system can handle.